# Binary Search Trees, how do you find maximum?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I've been working with Binary Search Trees in my spare time, and I want to be able to delete nodes from a tree.

In order to get this to work, I need to find the maximum value.  How do you go about doing that? Pseudo-code or hints would be appreciated. I'm stuck and not exactly sure how to even begin this.

Comment: easily answered by searching... http://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22binary+tree%22+find+maximum&kl=au-en

Comment: Why do you need to find the maximum value in order to delete nodes from the tree? (And ... pardon my skepticism, but is this really in your spare time or is it homework? It *sounds* a lot like homework.)

Comment: Definitely spare time.  I did an assignment about it a while back and didn't have to do anything with deleting.  I was looking around on my teacher's website and saw that he had a sample one referencing 'find max'.  I wanted to learn how to do it myself since I didn't feel like I grasped the entire concept myself.

Comment: Apologies for my comment (deleted), I was confused as to what the goal was.

Answer (score 5):

A binary search tree has the following properties:

> The left subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys less than the node's key.
>   The right subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys greater than the node's key.
>   Both the left and right subtrees must also be binary search trees.

With that definition in mind, it should be very easy to find the max.

Comment: indeed - just keep going to the right. The node with no right-child node contains the max value.

Answer (score 0):

A simple pseudocode would be this. It it is indepandant to binary search I think.

```
int maxi = 0
foreach(array as item) // or any other loop
    if item>maxi then maxi = item
```